# updating an index on an subselect entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

In my project, I have entities that I cannot change, but I need to create an index on top one of them. That an example what I want to archive:

That is the entities that I cannot change:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "main")
public class FirstEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private SecondEntity secondaryEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "secondary")
public class SecondEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;

}
```

My entity

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@Subselect("select * from main")
//@Table(name = "main")
//@Immutable
public class ThirdEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private SecondEntity secondaryEntity;

    @Transient
    @GenericField(sortable = Sortable.YES)
    @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = {
            @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "secondaryEntity"))
    })
    public String getName() {
        return secondaryEntity.getName();
    }
}
```

Whenever the SecondEntity changes, the index for ThirdEntity remains the same.

I wrote a small/simple example https://github.com/YaroslavTir/reindex-subselect-entity

I have in mind a workaround solution. Using hibernateListeners and rebuild index for ThirdEntity by hand, but that is not really nice solution.

Comment: Have you considered using programmatic mapping instead of adding a new entity with subselect?


  [1]: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#hsearch-mapping-programmaticapi

Comment: @mark_o The programmatic mapping does not solve the issue, I should keep the index up-to-date by myself anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your indexing dependency annotation is incomplete, it should be something like:

```
   @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = {
        @ObjectPath(
            @PropertyValue(propertyName = "secondaryEntity"),
            @PropertyValue(propertyName = "name")
        )
    })
```

Comment: Thank you. But that doesn't really help. I have now another issue: Unable to find the inverse side of the association on type. That is not bidirectional relation and cannot be it. I also don't see who can be  @AssociationInverseSide used this case.

Comment: @yaroslavTir https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-reindexonupdate